# FormBox in pretty strings

Tags: output-formatting, formatting, boxes

My goal is to write usage messages in the same style as Mathematica's built-in ones, such as `List::usage`.  This involves a mess of `StyleBox` commands:

```
"\!\(\*RowBox[{\"{\", RowBox[{SubscriptBox[StyleBox[\"e\", \"TI\"],
StyleBox[\"1\", \"TR\"]], \",\", SubscriptBox[StyleBox[\"e\", \"TI\"],
StyleBox[\"2\", \"TR\"]], \",\", StyleBox[\"\[Ellipsis]\", \"TR\"]}],
\"}\"}]\) is a list of elements. "
```

Rather than figuring out the styles `"TI"`, `"TR"` appropriate for each situation, I determined that using `TraditionalForm` does a good job of emulating it (perhaps `T` in `"TI"` and `"TR"` stands for `Traditional`?).

To get boxes into a string one can use the `\!\(...\)` syntax or the `\*...` syntax, so for instance, I can get a `FractionBox` of `a` over `b` by doing

```
"\*" <> ToString[ToBoxes[a/b]]
```

Better, `"\*" <> ToString[ToBoxes[a/b,TraditionalForm],InputForm]` (the use of `InputForm` makes *Mathematica* escape some strings as needed in more complicated expressions).  The `TraditionalForm` only makes `a` and `b` be italicized, but does not put it in the font that `a/b//TraditionalForm` gives.

After digging a bit, the question boils down to why

```
"\*FormBox[FractionBox[a,b],TraditionalForm]"

"\*FormBox[FractionBox[a,b],TraditionalForm]" // TraditionalForm
```

give different outputs (different fonts), and how to get the second output, hopefully without having to understand the precise styles used by `TraditionalForm`.

Comment: TR stands for Times Regular; TI for TimesItalic

Comment: @m_goldberg Thanks.